# Fixing broken unity configuration on clean install using old home directory?

Tags: unity, 11.10

My computer locked up during upgrade to 11.10.  I ended up copying my whole home directory to a second partition and reinstalling marking that partition as mount point for home and not formatting.  I had to fix some permission/ownership issues on ~/.ICEauthority and then recursively chowned the home directory.  After reboot I was able to log in successfully.

After logging in there is no side bar.  At the top I have the File/Edit/View/../Help menus but I cant seem to get anything to run.

I've been googling, trying to find a command-line solution to reset all UI settings to default since I'm sure is some of the configuration files in my home directory thats screwing it all up but I haven't found anything that works.

I really would like to get ubuntu back working by Monday or I'll have to boot up into windows and ssh into the school linux server to get my work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1 
unity --reset-icons 
unity --reset
```

Comment: `unity --reset` gives me the error `unity-panel-service: no process found`. Research online leads me to believe it's a driver issue. I think I'm just going to reinstall letting it make a new home directory and copy stuff over.